# EF 4.3.1 Migration Exception - AlterColumn defaultValueSql creates same default constraint name for different tables

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.3, entity-framework-migrations

I have a DB that I created using the OOB database initializer, and I am using Code First with EF 4.3.1.

I wanted to take advantage of the new "IgnoreChanges" flag on the Add-Migration cmdlet, so that I can alter some of my columns and add a default SQL value.  Essentially, some of my entities have a column named DateLastUpdated, which I would like to set the DEFAULT to the sql expression GETDATE().

I created the InitialMigration using "add-migration InitialMigration -ignorechanges", and then I added the following to the Up() and Down():

```
public override void Up()
{
    AlterColumn("CustomerLocations", "DateLastUpdated", c => c.DateTime(defaultValueSql: "GETDATE()"));
    AlterColumn("UserReportTemplates", "DateLastUpdated", c => c.DateTime(defaultValueSql: "GETDATE()"));
    AlterColumn("Chains", "DateLastUpdated", c => c.DateTime(defaultValueSql: "GETDATE()"));
}

public override void Down()
{
    AlterColumn("CustomerLocations", "DateLastUpdated", c => c.DateTime());
    AlterColumn("UserReportTemplates", "DateLastUpdated", c => c.DateTime());
    AlterColumn("Chains", "DateLastUpdated", c => c.DateTime());
}
```

Then I tried running "Update-Database -verbose", but I see that it is trying to create the same named default constraint on the database, and SQL throws an exception:

```
Applying explicit migrations: [201203221856095_InitialMigration].
Applying explicit migration: 201203221856095_InitialMigration.
ALTER TABLE [CustomerLocations] ADD CONSTRAINT DF_DateLastUpdated DEFAULT GETDATE() FOR [DateLastUpdated]
ALTER TABLE [CustomerLocations] ALTER COLUMN [DateLastUpdated] [datetime]
ALTER TABLE [UserReportTemplates] ADD CONSTRAINT DF_DateLastUpdated DEFAULT GETDATE() FOR [DateLastUpdated]
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): There is already an object named 'DF_DateLastUpdated' in the database.
Could not create constraint. See previous errors.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(DbAsyncResult result, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteSql(DbTransaction transaction, MigrationStatement migrationStatement)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.ExecuteSql(DbTransaction transaction, MigrationStatement migrationStatement)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteOperations(String migrationId, XDocument targetModel, IEnumerable`1 operations, Boolean downgrading)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ApplyMigration(DbMigration migration, DbMigration lastMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.ApplyMigration(DbMigration migration, DbMigration lastMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Update(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.UpdateRunner.RunCore()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.Run()
There is already an object named 'DF_DateLastUpdated' in the database.
Could not create constraint. See previous errors.
```

It looks like EF is creating the DEFAULT constraint by appending "DF_" with the name of the column, but not using the name of the table, to make this unique to the table.  Is this a known bug, or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: check Elyas answer. it is a nice solution

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems it's a known bug: [msdn forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adonetefx/thread/b4ba0dd5-de0f-470e-af20-4bc09a1d8622)

Andrew J Peters Microsoft (MSFT) replied:

> Thanks for reporting this. The issue will be fixed for RTM.
>
> A possible workaround is to initially make the column nullable, which
>   will prevent Migrations from generating the extra DEFAULT constraint.
>   Once the column is created, then it can be altered back to
>   non-nullable.

But it's definitelly not fixed in EF 4.3.1. Here is relevant part of the source:

```
// Type: System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Sql.SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator
// Assembly: EntityFramework, Version=4.3.1.0, 
// Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
namespace System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Sql
{
  public class SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator : MigrationSqlGenerator
  {
     protected virtual void Generate(AlterColumnOperation alterColumnOperation)
     {
      //...
      writer.Write("ALTER TABLE ");
      writer.Write(this.Name(alterColumnOperation.Table));
      writer.Write(" ADD CONSTRAINT DF_");
      writer.Write(column.Name);
      writer.Write(" DEFAULT ");
      //...
```

So EF doesn't try to make the constraint name unique.

You should try the workaround and report it as a bug.

EDIT:
I've just realized that above mentioned `Generate` method is `virtual` so in the worst case you can inherit from `SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator` and fix the SQL generation and set it as the sql generator in Configuration.cs:

```
public Configuration()
{
    AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
    SetSqlGenerator("System.Data.SqlClient", 
        new MyFixedSqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator());
}
```

EDIT 2:

I think the best thing to do until it fixed to fall back to raw SQL:

```
public override void Up()
{
    Sql(@"ALTER TABLE [CustomerLocations] ADD CONSTRAINT 
        DF_CustomerLocations_DateLastUpdated 
        DEFAULT GETDATE() FOR [DateLastUpdated]");
    Sql(@"ALTER TABLE [CustomerLocations] ALTER COLUMN 
        [DateLastUpdated] [datetime]");
    //...
}
```

Comment: where did you get the code for EF?  I am using Reflector, but a chunk of that Generate method is probably using a lot of lambdas, funcs/actions, and anonymous stuff, so Reflector doesn't give me a good version of it to copy and modify.

Comment: I've used the built in decompiler in Resharper (you can use the free Jetbrains decompiler [dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/index.html?topDP)) and Telerik's JustDecompile also generates almost the same source.. but both contains lots of lambads :( so its not directly reusable.

Comment: @ThiagoSilva I think the easiest thing to do is to write this kind of migration in raw SQL until this bug fixed. I've updated my answer.

Comment: One year later, still not fixed in EF5.

Comment: Appears to have been fixed now these constraints are named DF_tableName_columnName according to https://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/EntityFramework.SqlServer/SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator.cs

Answer (score 7):

Ok, based on nemesv's answer (accepted), here's how I ended up fixing the problem for now, until a fix is officially issued:

```
internal class MyFixedSqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator : SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator
{
    protected override void Generate(AlterColumnOperation alterColumnOperation)
    {
        if (alterColumnOperation == null)
            throw new ApplicationException("alterColumnOperation != null");

        ColumnModel column = alterColumnOperation.Column;
        if ((column.DefaultValue != null) || !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(column.DefaultValueSql))
        {
            using (IndentedTextWriter writer = Writer())
            {
                writer.Write("ALTER TABLE ");
                writer.Write(this.Name(alterColumnOperation.Table));
                writer.Write(" ADD CONSTRAINT DF_");
                writer.Write(alterColumnOperation.Table + "_"); //   <== THIS IS THE LINE THAT FIXES THE PROBLEM
                writer.Write(column.Name);
                writer.Write(" DEFAULT ");
                writer.Write(column.DefaultValue != null ? base.Generate(column.DefaultValue) : column.DefaultValueSql);
                writer.Write(" FOR ");
                writer.Write(this.Quote(column.Name));
                this.Statement(writer);
            }
        }
        using (IndentedTextWriter writer2 = Writer())
        {
            writer2.Write("ALTER TABLE ");
            writer2.Write(this.Name(alterColumnOperation.Table));
            writer2.Write(" ALTER COLUMN ");
            writer2.Write(this.Quote(column.Name));
            writer2.Write(" ");
            writer2.Write(this.BuildColumnType(column));
            if (column.IsNullable.HasValue && !column.IsNullable.Value)
            {
                writer2.Write(" NOT NULL");
            }
            this.Statement(writer2);
        }
    }
}


internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<MyDbContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;

        SetSqlGenerator("System.Data.SqlClient", new MyFixedSqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator());
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: I ran into a problem where `alterColumnOperation.Table` included the schema, resulting in an invalid name for the constraint (like 'DF_dbo.MyTable_MyColumn'). I fixed it with this helper method : `private string RemoveSchema(string name){ return name.Split('.').Last(); }`

Comment: don't know if it's any safer, but in case they change the default EF method, instead of the second `using IndentedTextWriter ...` block, you could set the default values to `null` and let the base method finish creating the clause:

    `column.DefaultValue = null;
    column.DefaultValueSql = null;
    base.Generate(alterColumnOperation);`

Answer (score 1):

This solution tested in EF 6.1.3. most probably work on previous versions.

You can implement a custom sql generator class derived from SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator from System.Data.Entity.SqlServer namespace:

```
using System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Model;
using System.Data.Entity.SqlServer;

namespace System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Sql{
    internal class FixedSqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator : SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator {
        protected override void Generate(AlterColumnOperation alterColumnOperation){
            ColumnModel column = alterColumnOperation.Column;
            var sql = String.Format(@"DECLARE @ConstraintName varchar(1000);
            DECLARE @sql varchar(1000);
            SELECT @ConstraintName = name   FROM sys.default_constraints
                WHERE parent_object_id = object_id('{0}')
                AND col_name(parent_object_id, parent_column_id) = '{1}';
            IF(@ConstraintName is NOT Null)
                BEGIN
                set @sql='ALTER TABLE {0} DROP CONSTRAINT [' + @ConstraintName+ ']';
            exec(@sql);
            END", alterColumnOperation.Table, column.Name);
                this.Statement(sql);
            base.Generate(alterColumnOperation);
            return;
        }
        protected override void Generate(DropColumnOperation dropColumnOperation){
            var sql = String.Format(@"DECLARE @SQL varchar(1000)
                SET @SQL='ALTER TABLE {0} DROP CONSTRAINT [' + (SELECT name
                    FROM sys.default_constraints
                    WHERE parent_object_id = object_id('{0}')
                    AND col_name(parent_object_id, parent_column_id) = '{1}') + ']';
            PRINT @SQL;
                EXEC(@SQL); ", dropColumnOperation.Table, dropColumnOperation.Name);

                    this.Statement(sql);
            base.Generate(dropColumnOperation);
        }
    }
}
```

and set this configuration:

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<MyDbContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;

        SetSqlGenerator("System.Data.SqlClient", new FixedSqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator ());
    }
    ...
}
```