# EF Migrations: Can't add DateTime column

Tags: datetime, entity-framework-migrations

I'm using ASP.Net 4 EF 4.3.1 Code First Migrations.

I have an existing model class. I've added a property to it:

```
public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }
```

When I run update-database -force -verbose I get:

> ALTER TABLE [MyTable] ADD [LastUpdated] [datetime] NOT NULL DEFAULT
>   '0001-01-01T00:00:00.000' 
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
>   (0x80131904): The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data
>   type resulted in an out-of-range value.
>   The statement has been terminated.

I'm going to guess this relates to the implied default value being used in the generated SQL - it would appear to be complaining that the varchar it used to initialize things is data lost.

Comment: It's not my default - EF Code First Migrations is generating this SQL automatically for any new, not-null DateTime property/column.

Comment: The SQL `DateTime` datatype has a min value of 1 jan 1753. The .NET Datetime has a min value of 1 jan 0001. Unfortunately, conflicts are common.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer to this problem of not being able to add a non-null DateTime column is the same as the problem of getting 2 default values specified for a DateTime column:
[EF 4.3.1 Migration Exception - AlterColumn defaultValueSql creates same default constraint name for different tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9830216/ef-4-3-1-migration-exception-altercolumn-defaultvaluesql-creates-same-default/)

That is, it's been broken a long time, and you can workaround it by migrating with it nullable:

```
public DateTime? LastUpdated { get; set; }

PM> update-database
```

Then migrate again with it not null to get where you intended:

```
public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }

PM> update-database
```

Comment: In my case, it was necessary to remove `.IsRequired()` in fluent api too before to put it back. Thanks