# How can I override SQL scripts generated by MigratorScriptingDecorator

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

**Using Entity Framework 4.3.1 Code first, and Data Migrations.**

I have written a utility to automatically generate the Migration scripts for a target database, using the MigratorScriptingDecorator.

However, sometimes when re-generating the target database from scratch, the generated script is invalid, in that it declares a variable with the same name twice.

The variable name is **@var0**.

This appears to happen when there are multiple migrations being applied, and when at least two result in a default constraint being dropped.

The problem occurs both when generating the script form code, and when using the Package Manager console command:

```
Update-Database -Script
```

Here are the offending snippets form the generated script:

```
DECLARE @var0 nvarchar(128)
SELECT @var0 = name
FROM sys.default_constraints
WHERE parent_object_id = object_id(N'SomeTableName')
```

and

```
DECLARE @var0 nvarchar(128)
SELECT @var0 = name
FROM sys.default_constraints
WHERE parent_object_id = object_id(N'SomeOtherTableName')
```

I would like to be able to override the point where it generates the SQL for each migration, and then add a "GO" statement so that each migration is in a separate batch, which would solve the problem.

Anyone have any ideas how to do this, or if I'm barking up the wrong tree then maybe you could suggest a better approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So with extensive use of [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ilspy.ashx) and some pointers in [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9831375/703714) I found a way.

Details below fo those interested.

**Problem**

The `SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator` is the class ultimately responsible for creating the SQL statements that get executed against the target database or scripted out when using the `-Script` switch in the Package Manager console or when using the `MigratorScriptingDecorator`.

**Workings**

Examining the Genearate method in the `SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator` which is responsible for a `DROP COLUMN`, it looks like this:

```
protected virtual void Generate(DropColumnOperation dropColumnOperation)
{
    RuntimeFailureMethods
        .Requires(dropColumnOperation != null, null, "dropColumnOperation != null");
    using (IndentedTextWriter indentedTextWriter = 
        SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator.Writer())
    {
        string value = "@var" + this._variableCounter++;
        indentedTextWriter.Write("DECLARE ");
        indentedTextWriter.Write(value);
        indentedTextWriter.WriteLine(" nvarchar(128)");
        indentedTextWriter.Write("SELECT ");
        indentedTextWriter.Write(value);
        indentedTextWriter.WriteLine(" = name");
        indentedTextWriter.WriteLine("FROM sys.default_constraints");
        indentedTextWriter.Write("WHERE parent_object_id = object_id(N'");
        indentedTextWriter.Write(dropColumnOperation.Table);
        indentedTextWriter.WriteLine("')");
        indentedTextWriter.Write("AND col_name(parent_object_id, 
                                                       parent_column_id) = '");
        indentedTextWriter.Write(dropColumnOperation.Name);
        indentedTextWriter.WriteLine("';");
        indentedTextWriter.Write("IF ");
        indentedTextWriter.Write(value);
        indentedTextWriter.WriteLine(" IS NOT NULL");
        indentedTextWriter.Indent++;
        indentedTextWriter.Write("EXECUTE('ALTER TABLE ");
        indentedTextWriter.Write(this.Name(dropColumnOperation.Table));
        indentedTextWriter.Write(" DROP CONSTRAINT ' + ");
        indentedTextWriter.Write(value);
        indentedTextWriter.WriteLine(")");
        indentedTextWriter.Indent--;
        indentedTextWriter.Write("ALTER TABLE ");
        indentedTextWriter.Write(this.Name(dropColumnOperation.Table));
        indentedTextWriter.Write(" DROP COLUMN ");
        indentedTextWriter.Write(this.Quote(dropColumnOperation.Name));
        this.Statement(indentedTextWriter);
    }
}
```

You can see it keeps track of the variables names used, but **this only appears to keep track within a batch, i.e. a single migration**. So if a migratin contains more than one `DROP COLUM` the above works fine, but if there are two migrations which result in a `DROP COLUMN` being generated then the `_variableCounter` variable is reset.

No problems are experienced when not generating a script, as each statement is executed immediately against the database (I checked using SQL Profiler).

If you generate a SQL script and want to run it as-is though you have a problem.

**Solution**

I created a new `BatchSqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator` inheriting from `SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator` as follows (note you need `using System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Sql;`):

```
public class BatchSqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator : SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator
{
    protected override void Generate
       (System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Model.DropColumnOperation dropColumnOperation)
    {
        base.Generate(dropColumnOperation);

        Statement("GO");
    }
}
```

Now to force the migrations to use your custom generator you have two options:

1. If you want it to be integrated into the Package Manager console, add the below line to your `Configuration` class:

   ```
      SetSqlGenerator("System.Data.SqlClient", 
                      new BatchSqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator());
   ```
2. If you're generating the script from code (like I was), add a similar line of code to where you have your Configuration assembly in code:

   ```
   migrationsConfiguration.SetSqlGenerator(DataProviderInvariantName, 
                      new BatchSqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator());
   ```

Comment: Do you think a similar workaround might be possible for the sql generated for normal direct table inserts?