# How to create model from database preserving 'default' constraint values

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My existing table contains nearly 50 columns, most of them have the 'default' constraint.

I have created the model based on this database table. All seemed ok, until i tried to insert a new row. I've got a sql server error stating that some column cannot be null. It appears that creating a model from the database did not preserve the default constraints.

I edited the model manually adding all the defaults and after that inserting didn't fail.

So my question is, how do i create a model that automatically picks up default constraints associated to the columns?

Using mvc4, visual studio 2010, sql server 2008 r2.

Google search didnt make sense as all the people seemed to be talking about something different than what i need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you have a number of options. You could set the default values in the Model's default constructor. I think this is the better solution.

If you must have the default constraints in your database you could do set `defaultValueSql` in your data migrations like this:

```
AddColumn("ExistingTable", "NewColumn",c => c.Int(nullable: false, defaultValueSql: "0"));
```

Comment: I may have poorly described the situation or i dont understand your solution. In my project, i have added the EntityDataModel (.edmx) under the 'models'. Opened it, and throught right click i selected 'Generate model from database', selected my table and clicked add. It created the entity and all the table fields had the correct data types, but they had no default constraint imported from the database, thats the problem. Your solution seems to tell that i have to manually add for each and every column, where i want to find a way to do it automatically. Maybe i missed some option or function(?)

Comment: There is no "default value" attribute that it can generate on your properties (unlike [Required] and such). You have to assign the default values via the default constructor (parameterless) of the class.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure my answer from [Possible to default DateTime field to GETDATE() with Entity Framework Migrations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8594431/possible-to-default-datetime-field-to-getdate-with-entity-framework-migrations/21024108#21024108) will work for you too. By using a modified MigrationCodeGenerator class and iterating through the operations list you can update the columns and add DefaultValueSql values based on whatever rules you need.