# Using Entity Framework 6, Custom Code-First Migrations & CSharpMigrationCodeGenerator

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I recently started using Entity Framework 6's code-first custom migrations.  It's working well, but one thing I'd like to do is generate a pair of `CreateIndex()` and `DropIndex()` statements when attempting to rename an index, instead of using `RenameIndex()` like the default `CSharpMigrationCodeGenerator` wants to.

For example, I currently use data annotations in a fluent mapping to rename an index like this:

```
Property(x => x.TeacherId).HasColumnAnnotation("Index", new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("IX_Students_TeacherId")));
```

The problem here is that by default EF6 wants to generate the following code when I add a new migration to capture this change to the model:

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;

namespace MyApp.Migrations
{
    public partial class RenameIndexTest : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            // BAD: [RenameIndex] will generate a "EXEC sp_rename" statement.
            RenameIndex(table: "dbo.Students", name: "IX_TeacherId", newName: "IX_Students_TeacherId");
        }

        public override void Down()
        {
            RenameIndex(table: "dbo.Students", name: "IX_Students_TeacherId", newName: "IX_TeacherId");
        }
    }
}
```

But what I really need EF6 to generate is this:

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;

namespace MyApp.Migrations
{
    public partial class RenameIndexTest : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            // GOOD: We generate separate SQL statements to drop & add the index.
            DropIndex(table: "dbo.Students", name: "IX_TeacherId");
            CreateIndex(table: "dbo.Students", name: "IX_Students_TeacherId", column: "TeacherId");
        }

        public override void Down()
        {
            DropIndex(table: "dbo.Students", name: "IX_Students_TeacherId");
            CreateIndex(table: "dbo.Students", name: "IX_TeacherId", column: "TeacherId");
        }
    }
}
```

Our data team has a hard requirement that developers use T-SQL `DROP`/`CREATE` statements when renaming indexes.  Thus far, I haven't been able to find a way to override the behavior of the `RenameIndex()` statement, using a custom class that uses `CSharpMigrationCodeGenerator` as its base class, because the `RenameIndexOperation` class doesn't have any information about the column(s) an index has been created on.

This is as far as I've been able to get on my own:

```
namespace MyApp.Migrations
{
    internal class CustomCSharpMigrationCodeGenerator : CSharpMigrationCodeGenerator
    {
        protected override string Generate(IEnumerable<MigrationOperation> operations, string @namespace, string className)
        {
            var customizedOperations = new List<MigrationOperation>();

            foreach (var operation in operations)
            {
                if (operation is RenameIndexOperation)
                {
                    var renameIndexOperation = operation as RenameIndexOperation;

                    var dropIndexOperation = new DropIndexOperation(operation.AnonymousArguments)
                    {
                        Table = renameIndexOperation.Table,
                        Name = renameIndexOperation.Name
                    };

                    var createIndexOperation = new CreateIndexOperation(operation.AnonymousArguments)
                    {
                        Table = renameIndexOperation.Table,
                        Name = renameIndexOperation.NewName,

                        // HELP: How do I get this information about the existing index?
                        // HELP: How do I specify what columns the index should be created on?
                        IsUnique = false,
                        IsClustered = false
                    };

                    // Do not generate a RenameIndex() statement; instead, generate a pair of DropIndex() and CreateIndex() statements.
                    customizedOperations.Add(dropIndexOperation);
                    customizedOperations.Add(createIndexOperation);
                }
                else
                {
                    customizedOperations.Add(operation);
                }
            }

            return base.Generate(customizedOperations, @namespace, className);
        }
    }
}
```

Does this make sense?  And more importantly, does anyone have any suggestions or ideas on how to proceed?  Either way, thanks in advance!

Comment: You might be able to get close to that with a custom SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator. See http://romiller.com/2012/01/16/customizing-code-first-migrations-provider/ You can intercept the CreateIndexOperation() and write your own SQL. See here also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8594431/possible-to-default-datetime-field-to-getdate-with-entity-framework-migrations

Comment: I'm trying to intercept `RenameIndexOperation`, not `CreateIndexOperation`.  The index already exists before I add my migration to set it properly.

Also, 
[`CreateIndexOperation` inherits from `IndexOperation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.migrations.model.createindexoperation(v=vs.113).aspx), which exposes the Columns property I need.  However, [RenameIndexOperation inherits from MigrationOperation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.migrations.model.renameindexoperation(v=vs.113).aspx), which does **not** expose it.

Comment: @SteveGreene: Sorry, I ran out of space above.  Basically, I need a way to rewrite a `RenameIndexOperation` as a pair of `DropIndexOperation` and `CreateIndexOperation` operations.  Simply intercepting my `CreateIndexOperation` won't work.

Comment: @SteveGreene: That's exactly what I said in my original posting... my last code snippet even illustrates how I'm unable to do exactly that.

Comment: Sorry, brain dead Monday. You could pass in what you need from the migration using the AnonymousArguments: RenameIndex(table: "dbo.Students", name: "IX_TeacherId", newName: "IX_Students_TeacherId", anonymousArguments: new { SortField = "MyField", SortOrder = "Descending" }); Then access them via createIndexOperation.AnonymousArguments.TryGetValue("SortField", out myfield); http://romiller.com/2012/01/16/customizing-code-first-migrations-provider/

Comment: @SteveGreene: The problem is that, when I intercept the `RenameIndexOperation` call, I don't have what I need to pass along to the other create/drop operations.  I see what you're saying about using the `AnonymousArguments` parameter to pass the info along, but the `RenameIndexOperation` lacks info about the index columns -- I need that info so that I can pass it to the create/drop operations.

Comment: It will get that info if you add it as anonymous argument from the Up() code, but one could argue your might as well just use Sql("DROP INDEX ..."); and Sql("CREATE INDEX ...");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm closing this question out.  I was never able to do exactly what I sought to... it wasn't a dealbreaker, I simply was hoping EF6 had some way of (easily) exerting control over the name of indexes being created.

IIRC, I did what **@steve-greene** suggested and manually specified the name of the index using the `Sql()` method.