# Automatic CreatedAt and UpdatedAt fields OnModelCreating() in ef6

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I have `CreatedAt` and `UpdatedAt` columns in my `User` model.

`User.cs`

```
public string Name { get; set; }
public DateTime? CreatedAt { get; set; }
public DateTime? UpdatedAt { get; set; }
```

**Requirement**

- When we `SaveChanges()` user records, `CreatedAt` and `UpdatedAt` should automatically saved e.g: `DateTime.UtcNow`
- When I update `User` record, only `UpdatedAt` column should get updated to current date time.
- And this should happen automatically for all other models, may be some configuration in `OnModelCreating()`.
- I want this behavior to find `latest` records from the database, and other places too.
- I am using `code first` migration approach
- I am using MySQL server, `MySql.Data`, `MySql.Data.Entity.EF6`.

**UPDATE**

I added `BaseEntity.cs` model

```
public abstract class BaseEntity
    {
        public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
        public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }
    }
```

Inheriting User from BaseEntity

```
public class User : BaseEntity
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public int FullName { get; set; }
}
```

and updated migrations to include `defaultValueSql()`

```
AddColumn("dbo.Users", "CreatedAt", c => c.DateTime(nullable: false, precision: 0, defaultValueSql: "NOW()"));
AddColumn("dbo.Users", "UpdatedAt", c => c.DateTime(nullable: false, precision: 0, defaultValueSql: "NOW()"));"
```

Now, need a way to fix `UpdatedAt` column in each update.

Comment: use database first, then the implement by sql?

Comment: No, I am using code first. I found `AddColumn("dbo.Users", "CreatedAt", c => c.DateTime(nullable: false, precision: 0, defaultValueSql: "UTC_TIMESTAMP()"));` but `update-migration` is giving syntax error.

Comment: but running `select UTC_TIMESTAMP();` in mysql query gives current date time stamp

Comment: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UTC_TIMESTAMP()' at line 1`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Finally, Found solution for my problem. Because we can change our database from `MySql` to `postgresql` or `Ms Sql server`, so adding default value using sql query doesn't seems like correct solution.

Here is how I have solved it.

Add `Base` model

```
 public abstract class BaseEntity
 {
    public DateTime? CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public DateTime? UpdatedAt { get; set; }
 }
```

Inherit all your models from this base model, In my case it is `User`

```
public class User : BaseEntity
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public int FullName { get; set; }
}
```

don't forget to generate migrations if you are using code first approach. Migration should be simple enough:

Example:

```
AddColumn("dbo.Users", "CreatedAt", c => c.DateTime(precision: 0));
AddColumn("dbo.Users", "UpdatedAt", c => c.DateTime(precision: 0));
```

And Final step is to override `SaveChanges()` and `SaveChangesAsync()` in your context:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        AddTimestamps();
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }

    public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync()
    {
        AddTimestamps();
        return await base.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    private void AddTimestamps()
    {
        var entities = ChangeTracker.Entries()
            .Where(x => x.Entity is BaseEntity && (x.State == EntityState.Added || x.State == EntityState.Modified));

        foreach (var entity in entities)
        {
            var now = DateTime.UtcNow; // current datetime

            if (entity.State == EntityState.Added)
            {
                ((BaseEntity)entity.Entity).CreatedAt = now;
            }
            ((BaseEntity)entity.Entity).UpdatedAt = now;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that for those using EF Core, this does not work. Entities cannot yet inherit fields from abstract base classes. MS calls this Table-Per-Concrete-Type, and it's not yet supported. Feature release target is EF 5.0, which is currently in preview so hopefully soon. This would make many domain models much cleaner. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance

Comment: It does in EF Core 7.0:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance#table-per-concrete-type-configuration

Answer (score 3):

I saw the @przbadu's post and I had a little difficult.
I am using dotnet core 2.2 and my override I needed to change the SaveChangeAsync method to:

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    AddTimestamps();
    return base.SaveChanges();
}

public override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken())
{
    AddTimestamps();
    return base.SaveChangesAsync();
}

private void AddTimestamps()
{
    var entities = ChangeTracker.Entries()
        .Where(x => x.Entity is BaseEntity && (x.State == EntityState.Added || x.State == EntityState.Modified));

    foreach (var entity in entities)
    {
        var now = DateTime.UtcNow; // current datetime

        if (entity.State == EntityState.Added)
        {
            ((BaseEntity)entity.Entity).CreatedAt = now;
        }
        ((BaseEntity)entity.Entity).UpdatedAt = now;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could define yourself a `interface` like this:

```
public interface ITiming {
  DateTime CreatedAt {get; set; }
  DateTime UpdatedAt {get; set; }
}
```

Now let every model you want implement this interface.
And write yourselve a `ExtionsionMethod` like this:

```
public static SaveChangesTimed(this YourDbContext _context, ITiming timed) {
   timed.CreatedAt = DateTime.Now;
   timed.UpdatedAt = Datetime.Now;
   _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Yggraz, but I have one question though: It looks like it will update `CreatedAt` and `UpdatedAt` everytime `SaveChanges()` is hit, but I want to updated `CreatedAt` for the first time and it should not change from that point, only `UpdatedAt` should change from next time. Please correct me if I misunderstood.

Comment: yes, if you want this, then you have to autoimplement `CreatedAt` [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8594431/possible-to-default-datetime-field-to-getdate-with-entity-framework-migrations) and use the Extension just for UpdatedAt