# Automatic CreatedAt and UpdatedAt with onModelCreating and a generic BaseEntity

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to implement something like [this accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45429719/automatic-createdat-and-updatedat-fields-onmodelcreating-in-ef6#new-answer) but my `BaseEntity` is a generic class which looks like this:

```
public abstract class BaseEntity<TKey>
{
    public TKey Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to implement Timestamp addition on the `SaveChangesAsync()` method, but I have no idea how to go about doing that. My code looks like this:

```
... 
var entries = ChangeTracker
            .Entries()
            .Where(e => e.Entity is BaseEntity && (
                    e.State == EntityState.Added
                    || e.State == EntityState.Modified));

foreach (var entityEntry in entries)
{
   ((BaseEntity)entityEntry.Entity).UpdatedAt = DateTime.Now;

   if (entityEntry.State == EntityState.Added)
   {
         ((BaseEntity)entityEntry.Entity).CreatedAt = DateTime.Now;
   }
}
```

but the issue is `BaseEntity` is a generic type so the comparison doesn't work.

Comment: Create non-generic `BaseEntity`, move non-generic fields there and inherit `BaseEntity<TKey>` from it.

Comment: Or make it implement an interface containing both DateTime properties. And use `ChangeTracker.Entries<IMyInterface>()...`.

Comment: @GuruStron I took your advice and implemented a `AuditedEntity` which had all the audit fields, then I made the `BaseEntity` to inherit from it. It worked actually, which solved the issue. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @KayAceElits was glad to help.