# Code First, set GetDate() on DateTime2 field

Tags: entity-framework-6, ef-code-first, getdate, datetime2

I've followed the examples like accepted here: [Possible to default DateTime field to GETDATE() with Entity Framework Migrations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8594431/possible-to-default-datetime-field-to-getdate-with-entity-framework-migrations)

In Sql server, the "Default Binding or Value" is now getting set to ('1900-01-01T00:00:00.000'), but not to GetDate() as I would expect.

```
public partial class InitialCreate : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        AddColumn("dbo.UserWordsModels", "DateAdded", c => c.DateTime(defaultValueSql: "GETDATE()"));

    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropColumn("dbo.UserWordsModels", "DateAdded");
    }
}
```

In the Model:

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }
```

One thing I may have different is I set this so all DateTime fields are DateTime2

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Properties<DateTime>().Configure(c => c.HasColumnType("datetime2"));}
```

Comment: What's the problem you are experiencing with `defaultValueSql: "GETDATE()"`?

Comment: It's not setting GetDate() in sql, it's setting it as  ('1900-01-01T00:00:00.000'). Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: The database-default value is only set if no value is provided in the INSERT/UPDATE statement. You apparently send DateTIme.MinValue.

Comment: That isn't the value inserted, that is the value in the "Default Binding or Value" which should be GetDate(), not ('1900-01-01T00:00:00.000').